# How to show this tags on intellij idea community

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tags, ide, show

Could someone tell me how to show this tags on intellij idea community (in this picture: name, email, dob,...). Thank you so much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpCKe.png)

(Ignored this sentence)
Maybe this feature have settings, but i dont know it name, or where it place... so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable/disable hint under the 'Editor - Inlay Hints'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are called Hints. You can access settings under Editor > Inlay hints.

The specific one you are looking for is Parameter names > Java > 'New' expressions